# Issue with iOS VoIP CallKit app when handling incoming call from locked screen

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, callkit

I'm working on an iOS app with VoIP functionality, and CallKit integration.  I've come across an issue that I can't seem to find any information about.  Here's what happens:

- The device is locked and an incoming call is received
- The CallKit incoming screen is displayed, and I accept the call
- The CallKit call-in-progress screen is displayed, and the call works normally
- I hit the device's home button, which results in the device's lock screen being displayed.  At this point there is a green status bar displayed for returning to the call
- I tap the green status bar.  At this point, the PIN entry screen for unlocking the device is displayed.
- If I enter my device PIN, my app opens in the foreground and its in-app call-in-progress screen is displayed

The problem is that I'd like to go back to the CallKit call-in-progress screen when tapping the green status bar from the lock screen.  Seems to me that would be the correct behavior.  But instead it is trying to open my app, which results in the PIN lock screen being displayed.  Seems like it should not try to open my app like this unless I explicitly try to open it in some manner.

Has anybody encountered this, or have any idea whether this is something that can be fixed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behavior. The CallKit call-in-progress screen is only displayed while the phone is locked. If you unlock it and you tap on the green bar, you will always be redirected to your app.

The only way to display the CallKit screen is to lock the phone again; but you should keep in mind that if you try to lock the phone without any headset attached to it, it will hang up the call.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to again go to  native UI from green Bar.